# How to copy stackalloc memory to/from array?

Tags: c#, arrays, stackalloc

When working with `stackalloc` memory I would like to copy its content to/from an array. I am looking for something similar to `Buffer.BlockCopy` which would allow me to pass offset in source data and offset in destination.

Is there is such method for `stackalloc` memory? Or in general -- how to copy memory in one go, without iterating element by element?

```
int i = 0;
double* window = stackalloc double[max_window_size];
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    window[i] = array[x, y];
    ++i;
}
```

**Important catch**: the array I am asking about already exists. So I cannot create an array from `stackalloc` memory and then copy this array to existing array, because it would invalidate whole point of using `stackalloc` in the first place.

Comment: You might want to look into using Span https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/03/25/c-7-series-part-10-spant-and-universal-memory-management/

Comment: Please show us a `stackalloc` [mcve] that does copy by iterating one at a time and we'll show you how to do it better.

Comment: @Enigmativity, here I copy from 2d array a row to a "window" allocated on stack. I would like to copy the content in one take to and from `stackalloc` memory.

Comment: @astrowalker it's still not a complete example... you've not defined array or y

Comment: @Mick, it is pretty simple, either there is analogy to `Buffer.BlockCopy` or not. If not, any further action is futile, if the former you simply are playing games, and I don't have time for this. I wish you happy day nevertheless.

Comment: @astrowalker - It's still not complete. Can you provide an example that I can copy, paste, and run in a Console App?

Comment: @astrowalker I've created a new question to discuss using Span to slice without copying of memory  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750582/span-and-two-dimensional-arrays/52750659#52750659

Comment: It can be achieved using Span. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881863/how-can-i-copy-from-a-readonlyspant-to-an-arrayt

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [Copy data from from IntPtr to IntPtr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45500615/6734314)

So to answer my own question one has to pin for a second the array (using `fixed` keyword) and this way one have two pointers at hand. `Buffer.MemoryCopy` does not have overload with offsets but will little pointer arithmetic you get desired effect.