# Span and two dimensional Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, multidimensional-array, system.memory

Is it possible to use the new [System.Memory Span struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) with two dimensional arrays of data?

```
double[,] testMulti = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
        { 9, 9.5f, 10, 11 },
        { 12, 13, 14.3f, 15 }
    };

double[] testArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string testString = "Hellow world";

testMulti.AsSpan(); // Compile error
testArray.AsSpan();
testString.AsSpan();
```

Whilst testArray and testString have a AsSpan extension, no such extension exists for testMulti.

Is the design of Span limited to working with single dimensional arrays of data?
I've not found an obvious way of working with the testMulti array using Span.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a `Span` with unmanaged memory. This will allow you to *Slice and Dice* indiscriminately.

```
unsafe
{
    Span<T> something = new Span<T>(pointerToarray, someLength); 
}
```

**Full Demo**

```
unsafe public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   double[,] doubles =  {
         { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
         { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
         { 9, 9.5f, 10, 11 },
         { 12, 13, 14.3f, 15 }
      };

   var length = doubles.GetLength(0) * doubles.GetLength(1);

   fixed (double* p = doubles)
   {
      var span = new Span<double>(p, length);
      var slice = span.Slice(6, 5);

      foreach (var item in slice)
         Console.WriteLine(item);
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
7
8
9
9.5
10
```

Other options would be to reallocate to a single dimension array, cop the penalty and *do not Pass-Go*

- `BlockCopy`
- or p/invoke `memcpy` directly and use `unsafe` and pointers
- `Cast<T>` eg `multiDimensionalArrayData.Cast<byte>().ToArray()`

The first 2 will be more performant for large arrays.

Comment: I think the length in your code is incorrect it should be var length = testMulti.GetLength(0) * testMulti.GetLength(1);

Comment: For lack of a better answer I'll mark this as the answer, obviously a solution that doesn't involve unsafe code would be preferable.  Converting the structure to a jagged array seems to be the best way around what I think is a gap in the design of System.Memory library.

Comment: @Mick yeah there is no suitable answer really and its one of implementation and design, internally span is unsafe and pointers to do its thing, using a jagged array in your case is suitable, yet not if need to slice through dimensions. Though a blanket solution even using pointers is not going to work that well either and fixed can only be used with certain types. All this is not so much a limitation of the feature or that it just hasnt been built, its the limitation of the CLR without reallocating. As such you can create a span by pointers which seems to fill in the gap

Comment: I think your length computation is oversized.  The documentation says that the Span constructor of T takes the *number of T elements*, not the size in bytes.  You can remove the `* sizeof(double)`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the new `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan` and `MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference` for this.

```cs
public static Span<T> AsSpan<T>(this Array array)
{
    return MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref Unsafe.As<byte, T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(array)), array.Length);
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/anifjN)

This works on all dimensions of arrays. If you want generic type inference to work, you will need separate functions for every rank (level of dimension), such as `AsSpan<T>(this T[,] array)` and `AsSpan<T>(this T[,,] array)`.

Answer (score 4):

As John Wu already mentioned spans are one dimensional.
You could of course implement a 2D span yourself, but Microsoft already did that for us.

Have a look into the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/high-performance/span2d).
You can find the addressing nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance/).
The package also provides a Memory2D.

```cs
 var arr = new int[,] { {1,2,3},{2,2,3},{3,2,3} };
 var spn = arr.AsSapn2D();
 // Now use it similar to a normal span
 // The access is of course a bit different since we are using a 2D data structure.
 Console.WriteLine(spn[0..2,..]);
```

Answer (score 1):

All spans are one-dimensional because memory is one-dimensional.

You can of course map all manner of structures onto one-dimensional memory, but the Span class won't do it for you. But you could easily write something yourself, for example:

```
public class Span2D<T> where T : struct
{
    protected readonly Span<T> _span;
    protected readonly int _width;
    protected readonly int _height;

    public Span2D(int height, int width)
    {
        T[] array = new T[_height * _width];
        _span = array.AsSpan();
    }

    public T this[int row, int column]
    {
        get
        {
            return _span[row * _height + column];
        }
        set
        {
            _span[row * _height + column] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The tricky part is implementing `Slice()`, since the semantics are sort of ambiguous for a two-dimensional structure. You can probably only slice this sort of structure by one of the dimensions, since slicing it by the other dimension would result in memory that is not contiguous.

Comment: This is a nifty idea as well

Comment: You can only accomodate a field of a `ref struct` type on another `ref struct`. `Span<T>` is a `ref struct` while, in your code, `Span2D<T>` is a class.

Comment: @EduardDumitru is correct - this code won't compile as-is. Either Span2D would need to be a `ref struct` instead of a class, or the class member holding the data would need to be a Memory instead of a Span.

Answer (score 0):

As @saruman I don't believe it's possible.

You will need to get a new single dimension array first using techniques shown in [Fast way to convert a two dimensional array to a List ( one dimensional )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132397/fast-way-to-convert-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-list-one-dimensional) or [Convert 2 dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641499/convert-2-dimensional-array), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's more success to be had working with a jagged array instead of a multidimensional array.

```
double[][] testMulti = 
    {
        new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        new double[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
        new double[] { 9, 9.5f, 10, 11 },
        new double[] { 12, 13, 14.3f, 15 }
    };

Span<double[]> span = testMulti.AsSpan(2, 1);
Span<double> slice = span[0].AsSpan(1, 2);

foreach (double d in slice)
    Console.WriteLine(d);

slice[0] = 10.5f;

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", testMulti[2]));

Console.ReadLine();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
9.5
10
9, 10.5, 10, 11
```

Comment: Strictly speaking not an answer to my question as the testMulti type is different.

Comment: Seems a little odd that this works for a jagged array but there's no easy solution for multidimensional arrays