# Vectorize ND-Array to 1D-Array as fast as possible

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to vectorize a n-dimensional array as 1-dimensional array in C# to later ease working using linear indexing (this whatever the type of the elements).

So far I was using `Buffer.BlockCopy` to do that (and even reshaping from n-dimensions to m-dimensions as long as the number of elements was not changing) but unfortunately I came across having to reshape arrays whose elements are not primitive types (double, single, int) and in this case `Buffer.BlockCopy` does not work (example array of `string` or whatever other non primitive type).

Currently the solution I have is to make special-case for non-primitive types:

```
/// <summary>Vectorize ND-array</summary>
/// <param name="arrayNd">ND-Array to vectorize.</param>
/// <returns>Surface copy as 1D array.</returns>
public static Array Vectorize(Array arrayNd)
{
    // Check arguments
    if (arrayNd == null) { return null; }
    var elementCount = arrayNd.Length;

    // Create 1D array
    var tarray = arrayNd.GetType();
    var telem = tarray.GetElementType();
    var array1D = Array.CreateInstance(telem, elementCount);

    // Surface copy
    if (telem.IsPrimitive)
    {
        // Block copy only works for array whose elements are primitive types (double, single, ...)
        var numberOfBytes = Buffer.ByteLength(arrayNd);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayNd, 0, array1D, 0, numberOfBytes);
    }
    else
    {
        // Slow version for other element types
        // NB: arrayNd.GetValue(...) does not support linear indexing so need to compute indices for each dimension (very slow !!)
        var indices = new int[arrayNd.Rank];
        for (var i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
        {
            var idx = i;
            for (var d = arrayNd.Rank - 1; d >= 0; d--)
            {
                var l = arrayNd.GetLength(d);
                indices[d] = idx % l;
                idx /= l;
            }

            array1D.SetValue(arrayNd.GetValue(indices), i);
        }
    }

    // Return as 1D
    return array1D;
}
```

So this works now all types:

```
var double1D = Vectorize(new double[3, 2, 5]); // Fast BlockCopy
var string1D = Vectorize(new string[3, 2, 5]); // Slow solution
```

I already have an `NEnumerator` class of my own to speed up computing indices (instead of using `modulo` as above) but maybe there is really fast way for just making this sort of "surface memcpy" ?

NB1: I'd like to avoid `unsafe` code but if it's the only way ...

NB2: I really want to work with `System.Array` (eventually I'll later do a bunch of `T[] Vectorize(T[,,,,] array)` overloads but that's not the issue)

Comment: Maybe you can come up with something with these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/memory-and-spans/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750582/span-and-two-dimensional-arrays

Comment: Do you really need this for arbitrary dimensions? I have rarely seen any array with more than 3 dimensions. Note that the array *value* might be a `Vector3` or some custom type.

Comment: And even the 3d arrays I have seen in the wild have been using jagged array for performance and memory handling reasons, i.e. `T[][,]` rather than `T[,,]`

Comment: @JonasH Data I work with are generally 2D to 4D (hardly ever 5D) and I wrote a library of Reshape, Sort, Permute, Mean, Max, etc.. functions in a very generic way (so it's easy to specialize and force to be type safe with `T[]`, `T[,]`, ... up to necessary)  ... The idea is not to be extremely fast (`NEnumerator` of my own is quite ok) ... here I was wondering if a fast and ready-to-use `BlockCopy` equivalent exist(ed) for non primitives because it sound pretty obvious data are 1D in memory so should be more fast to just do a buffer-like copy.

Comment: I have done the same thing, but for non-primitve types I do a shallow copy with `Array.Copy()` since `Buffer.BlockCopy()` isn't supported. There is also the `Marshal.Copy()` function to be explored.

Comment: @CitizenInsane - Trying to coax `C#` into a full array language is a noble and interesting endeavor. The addition of `Reshape()` alone inspired by Fortran would be a welcome addition to have. Having gone down the same roads myself, I ended up ditching native multi-dim arrays and creating a custom `Matrix` object with a linear array as a backing store with only support for rank 1 and rank 2 objects. But I can readily define diagonal, upper and lower triangular and symmetric matrices this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, Multidimensional arrays are kind of a pain to work with, in large part since it is so difficult to access the backing data. As far as I know there is no direct way to just copy all the elements for arbitrary types.

Because of this I tend to prefer a custom type for my 2D types that uses a linear array as backing storage, and index like `myArray[y * width + x]`. With this model the whole exercise becomes a no-op, and you can get a pointer to pass to native code, it works better with serialization etc.

For 3D/4D arrays you could use the same mode, but it seems like the best option for performance is allocate slices independently, i.e. `myArray[z][y * width + x]`, at least for large arrays. I have not worked with 4D arrays, but in general, I would avoid multidimensional arrays if performance is a concern. There might also be libraries out there that might suit your needs, but I'm not aware of any specific one.

However, looking at your code I would expect there to be some possible improvements. You are currently doing N calls to `GetLength`, modulus & divisions for *each* element. So I would expect something like this to be a bit faster:

```
public static Array MultidimensionalToLinear(Array arr)
{
    var rank = arr.Rank;
    var lengths = new int[rank];

    for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
    {
        lengths[i] = arr.GetLength(i);
    }

    var linearLength = arr.Length;
    var result = Array.CreateInstance(arr.GetType().GetElementType(), linearLength);
    var index = new int[rank];
    var linearIndex = 0;
    CopyRecursive(0, index, result, ref linearIndex);

    void CopyRecursive(int rank, int[] index, Array result, ref int linearIndex)
    {
        var lastIndex = index.Length - 1;
        if (rank == lastIndex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lengths[lastIndex]; i++)
            {
                index[lastIndex] = i;
                result.SetValue(arr.GetValue(index), linearIndex);
                linearIndex++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lengths[rank]; i++)
            {
                index[rank] = i;
                CopyRecursive(rank +1, index, result, ref linearIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, when measuring it seem like the performance improvement is fairly small. Probably due the code in `GetValue` dominating the runtime.