# Is there any faster way to do this? (Optimization or just straight-up doing it a different way)

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I'm trying to extract all elements of a 2D array and place them into a string, so far the code completes in an average of ~950ms but I was wondering if there's any faster way of doing this.

All the buffers are 256x256 `char` arrays.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 255; ii++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
    }
}
```

The full context of the code snippet above. The ~950ms measurement is for the `ExtractA()` function, with the other buffers taking a reasonable amount of time, but optimization would also be appreciated.

```
public static string ExportBuffer(int Buffer, int Line, int Dimension = 2, int Start = 0, int End = 255)
{
    string Export = "Test";

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 255; ii++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            BufferC[i, ii] = 'A';
        }
    }

    switch (Buffer)
    {
        default: throw new NotImplementedException("The buffer selected does not exist.");
        case 00:  ExtractDisplayBuffer(); break;
        case 01:        ExtractBufferA(); break;
        case 02:        ExtractBufferB(); break;
        case 03:        ExtractBufferC(); break;
    }
    void ExtractDisplayBuffer()
    {
        switch (Dimension)
        {
            case 0: ExtractX(); break;
            case 1: ExtractY(); break;
            case 2: ExtractA(); break;
        }
        void ExtractX()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractY()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractA()
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 255; ii++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void ExtractBufferA()
    {
        switch (Dimension)
        {
            case 0: ExtractX(); break;
            case 1: ExtractY(); break;
            case 2: ExtractA(); break;
        }
        void ExtractX()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractY()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractA()
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 255; ii++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void ExtractBufferB()
    {
        switch (Dimension)
        {
            case 0: ExtractX(); break;
            case 1: ExtractY(); break;
            case 2: ExtractA(); break;
        }
        void ExtractX()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractY()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractA()
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 255; ii++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void ExtractBufferC()
    {
        switch (Dimension)
        {
            case 0: ExtractX(); break;
            case 1: ExtractY(); break;
            case 2: ExtractA(); break;
        }
        void ExtractX()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractY()
        {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
            {
                Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
            }
        }
        void ExtractA()
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 255; ii++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    Export = Export + BufferC[i, ii];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Export;
}
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings in a loop. **Do not** use the `+` operator because it will perform a new allocation and copy for every iteration.

Comment: What is this `String.Append` method you're calling?

Comment: @Dai I was using it as shorthand for the `+` operator in my code, but it can be ignored. Updated the post for clarification. How would I go about using the `StringBuilder` method?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0

Comment: Also do not use multi-dim arrays, as they are really slow. Use a single array of `n*m` size, and the index of the `i,j` element is `index = i*m+j`

Comment: `ii` is not defined in `ExtractX` and `ExtractY` ? I bet the code above does not even compile.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I thought the (decades-old) multidimensional array perf issue was fixed in .NET 5?

Comment: @Dai - I guess I just dated myself. I feel like `Span<char>` would be appropriate here, including with `Index` and `Range` objects, but it is unclear from the code posted what the intent it. To me `ExtractBufferA()`, `ExtractBufferB()` and `ExtractBufferC()` all look the same.

Comment: The fastest way to copy an array is memory copy (memcpy() in C). If C# had a similar facility I guess it would be the fastest.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou .NET now has `Span2D<Char>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/high-performance/span2d - but there's no benefit to using a Span here because we don't need to slice 'n' dice the input (though `Span2D<Char>` vs `Char[,]` performance should be on-par with each other).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Span and two dimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750582/span-and-two-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan()` to create a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` from a 2D char array, and then you can pass that span to the `string` constructor.

I think this will be one of the more performant approaches:

```
var buffer = new char[256, 256];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) // Fill with some arbitrary daya.
    {
        buffer[i, j] = (char)('A' + (i * 256 + j) % 64);
    }
}

// Create the span.
var span = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(
    ref Unsafe.As<byte, char>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(buffer)),
    buffer.Length);

// Create the string from the span.
string s = new string(span);

// Show that the string contains the correct data.
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Note that creating a span in the code above does NOT copy any data. However, the data *will* be copied once in the call to `new string(span)`, but the implementation uses a very fast copy.

You might like to write a separate method to convert 2D arrays of any type to make the code more readable:

```
public static ReadOnlySpan<T> TwoDimensionalArrayAsSpan<T>(T[,] array)
{
    return MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(
        ref Unsafe.As<byte, T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetArrayDataReference(array)),
        array.Length);
}
```

Then creating the span would look like:

```
// Create the span.
var span = TwoDimensionalArrayAsSpan(buffer);
```

Comment: I benchmarked your code compared to mine - and while mine ran in 0.7ms, yours ran in **0.05ms** - _wow_. Upvoted!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73373888/14868997 But I'm not sure if this works in row-major or column-major order, and what OP's intention is.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to extract all elements of a 2D array and place them into a string, so far the code completes in an average of ~950ms but I was wondering if there's any faster way of doing this.

Something like the `Flatten` function here:

```
static void Main()
{
    Char[,] input2DCharArray = CreateSampleData();
    
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
    String asString = Flatten( input2DCharArray );
    
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine( "Took {0:N2}ms to render the 2D array to a string.", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds );
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine( asString );
}

public static String Flatten( Char[,] input2DCharArray )
{
    if( input2DCharArray is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input2DCharArray));

    Int32 w = input2DCharArray.GetLength(0);
    Int32 h = input2DCharArray.GetLength(1);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: w * h );
    for( Int32 x = 0; x < w; x++ )
    {
        for( Int32 y = 0; y < h; y++ )
        {
            Char c = input2DCharArray[x,y];
            _ = sb.Append( c );
        }
    }
    
    return sb.ToString();
}

private static Char[,] CreateSampleData()
{
    Random rng = new Random( Seed: 55378008 );
    
    const Int32 LENGTH = 256;
    Char[,] arr = new Char[LENGTH,LENGTH];
    for( Int32 x = 0; x < LENGTH; x++ )
    {
        for( Int32 y = 0; y < LENGTH; y++ )
        {
            // Char values are not 0x00 to 0x7F, because we don't want to print control-chars to stdout.
            // ...so we use the range 0x32 to 0x7E - or rather 0x00 to 0x4C, then add 0x32 to it:
            Int32 rndCharValue = 0x32 + rng.Next( maxValue: 0x4C );
            arr[x,y] = (Char)rndCharValue;
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

When I run this on .NET 7 in `DEBUG` mode on my (now somewhat aged) desktop in Linqpad the `Stopwatch sw` says it took **0.78ms** (less than 1 millisecond) to render the `Char[256,256]` to a `String`. (Running it in `RELEASE` mode didn't improve performance for me *at all*, interestingly).

Some caveats/notes/thougts:

- [For what seems like *forever*, .NET's *true* multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468832/why-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-net-slower-than-normal-arrays) (`T[,]`, `T[,,]`, as opposed to Java-style jagged-arrays) have always *inexplicitly* [had poor performance](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/5481) compared to 1-dimensional `T[]` arrays.

  - [But *eventually* they fixed it only about a year ago](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/70271) and [it shipped in .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7455).
  - So if you can't target .NET 7 or higher (like us poor sods stuck in the dead-end of the .NET Framework 4.x) you might want to consider instead using 1-dimensional arrays with some trivial extension-methods that convert 2D array indexes to a flat index - and vice-versa.
- This implementation is single-threaded, which will be faster than using multiple-threads for arrays sized below some threshold (and I have no idea what that threshold is - it could be a few hundred KB - or as high as tens of megabytes - it all depends on your machine).

  - Using multiple threads will be slower because there is significant overhead to kicking-off a multi-threaded, shared-memory workflow - such as needing to allocate *megabytes* of RAM for each new thread for each thread's default stack size and thread-local state.
  - You also can't share the `StringBuilder` between threads - so each thread can only produce a substring from its own chunk of the array, so at the end you'll be left with N-many `String` values (from N-many threads) that you'll need to concatenate (and in the right order too!), which will basically be *just as expensive* as doing it in a single thread.
  - Also, `Parallel.For` does not support multidimensional arrays btw.
- Recent versions of .NET have really started to optimize `String` and certain array operations by taking advantage of things like SIMD/SSE/AVX ISA extensions. But this mostly benefits programs that let the .NET BCL do the heavy-lifting instead of writing their own `for` loops.

  - Indeed: the .NET 7 x64 native code from my C# program above uses SSE instructions like `vcvtsi2sd` and `vmovdqu` - *but* those instructions don't appear inside `Flatten`: [instead they only appear in `CreateSampleData` and `Main`; the x64 for the `Flatten` method is (to my surprise) using *only* simpler opcodes like `push`, `sub`, `mov`, `xor`, `jle`, `imul`, etc](https://gist.github.com/daiplusplus/497d0d8c1841bacdb578b0193af509d2).