2D Non-Jagged Arrays
With int arr[4][2] in C++ I could iterate through rows, I could iterate through columns, perfect for pretty much anything.
In C# I can implement it as: int[10,10]. int[10][] is no good, as it's a jagged array, and I don't need a jagged one.
Now I need to pick each row and process each row separately, if I am willing to bloat my code with blocks of code that describe exactly how to do that. Isn't C# supposed to be an upgrade over C++ or at least easier to use? Why can't I have a simple matrix?
Instead of doing arr[0].Sum() to sum a row, I have to do something like arr.Take(y).Sum() - creating a new array along the way. But you can't do that, as LINQ doesn't support it.
The only way to do this now is List<List<int>>(). How do you deal with this?

@EduardG Does anything in Span2D look like what you want?

@AndrewMorton seems like I don't have access to that, maybe because I am on .NET Framework 4.7.2. Trying to figure out where to find it... I do have Span tho.

@EduardG Sounds like you'll just have to use for loops then?

Did C++ have a difference between 2D arrays and arrays-of-arrays?  If the center of the question being asked is how to do something in C# that was easy in C++ then syntax alone may not be enough to compare, as what appears to be the same syntax in different languages could mean very different things.  "How do you deal with this?" - By conceptually separating the two and using the most applicable structure for the task at hand.  And it sounds like the task at hand here is to use an array of arrays with linear access, rather than a 2D array with set access.

@AndrewMorton How do you select all 10 elements from row 0 of [50,10]? There doesn't seem to be a pratical way. I want to do "var row0Sum = Sum(array[0])".
In a for loop, I would have to sum them one by one, which isn't practical for my needs as Sum in my case is an expensive operation. Instead I have to declare a new array to hold each row and fill it using the source array through the for loop and only then hand it over to the Sum func.

"ArrayExtensions.GetColumn(T[][], Int32) Method" link

@David yeah, it's my amusement that a foundational piece of code and math logic is missing in C#. It's a simple matrix, and C# cannot represent it.
The task at hand is to efficiently declare a matrix of rows and columns, then pass each row to a function that is expensive to run (so can't run it for every single element, but has to be done row-by-row). In order to do that, I have to run another expensive algorithm to allocate a new array to represent my rows, instead of using the values in the already existing [,] array.

@rotabor I am on .NET Framework, and Microsoft.Toolkit ArrayExtensions is a Deprecated package that I rather not add to my solution to traverse an array row-by-row.
The reason I am on .NET is that I need low-level access to the Win32 API with PInvoke, which is not supported in .NET Core due to the its multi-platform compatibility.

I've decided to go with Jagged arrays instead so [x][]. I can't with this syntax and with the need to allocate every single row in X, but there doesn't seem to be a more elegant solution.

@EduardG It seems to me that you haven't given enough detail of the problem in the question. For example, why do you need to use Sum instead of +?

@EduardG P/Invoke is not excluded by .NET [Core]: Platform Invoke (P/Invoke).

This question has been appropriately edited. We deal with programming problems, not feelings and anything else is just meta commentary and distraction from the actual problem you have. Questions and answers posted here are not meant only for the person asking, but also to help others who have the same problem. Concise questions help others to recognize whether the problem they have is the same one quicker.

@DalijaPrasnikar that's very black and white, most of your logic is based on feelings believe it or not, certainly much more than you realize. I am just aware of that, and shining light on it, so we are aware rather than ignorant. Separating the two like that is just ignorance, especially when building a community. In any case, I take great offense to my words being edited without my permission and my comments being deleted. I feel oppressed.

Maybe just use this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/73373888/14868997 to create a Span. I agree you shouldn't get emotionally involved. Be dispassionate, and analyze the issue without getting worked up. As to feeling oppressed: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAA-G947ofg

See also this package https://github.com/VictorNicollet/NoAlloq for LINQ for spans. Or you can make your own extension methods.

@EduardG - there is no oppression here; just moderation of content to remove superfluous content (and moderation is a core tenet of this site). Feel free to post to [meta] if you have a specific issue with how your question has been moderated - just be prepared to hear the same feedback, as your mention of losing your mind in your original title, along with your all-caps outburst in your original question (along with other sarcasm, all-caps shock, etc), are things that should be removed, whether by you or a member of the community.

From Tim-Maes. Add methods for multi dimensional arrays
    public static T[] GetRow<T>(this T[,] array, int row)
    {
        var rowLength = array.GetLength(1);
        var result = new T[rowLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
            result[i] = array[row, i];
        }
        return result;
    }


That's exceedingly inefficient, creating a new array for each access.

I've selected it as an answer @Charlieface, as sadly I haven't found a way to do this without creating a new array. I ended up using jagged arrays myself. Shame on C#.
