# How can I copy from a ReadOnlySpan<T> to an Array<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

My class has a property `public byte[] Location{get;} = new byte[30];`

I want to be able to fill it from a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` but I cannot find any API methods allowing this.

The closest I've found is:

```
var array = span.Slice(0,30).ToArray();
Array.Copy(array, Locations, 30);
```

But having to create a new array just to copy from it seems really ugly... one array creation and 2 copies are involved. I could make the property settable but it's not really the intended design.

Am i missing some obvious method?

Comment: Did you find any other solutions for this task?

Comment: Not so far - I'm leaving it to gain a bit more attention otherwise I'll accept your answer which seems at least a bit better than my approach :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a `Span<byte>` to target your `Location` array, then use `CopyTo` for the copy:

```
var source = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Source).Slice(0, 30);
var target = new Span<byte>(Location, 0, 30); //Modify start & length as required

source.CopyTo(target);
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. For me this is even (a bit) faster than `Buffer.BlockCopy()` (which in turn is just as fast as "unsafing" out to `memcpy`.  Yes I benchmarked it 'cuz I had to know...  :)  YMMV